# Nativescript "WARNING: The Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly"

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, sdk, nativescript

This seems to be a common issue but I cannot seem to fix it regardless of how many solutions exist.

What I also don't understand is why **tns doctor** works fine on another user on the same machine however, I get the below error on my user. Any ideas?

```
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
⚠ Update available for component nativescript. Your current version is 6.7.8 and the latest available version is 8.1.5.
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
✔ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Xcode is installed and is configured properly.
✔ xcodeproj is installed and is configured properly.
✔ CocoaPods are installed.
✔ CocoaPods update is not required.
✔ CocoaPods are configured properly.
✔ Your current CocoaPods version is newer than 1.0.0.
✔ Python installed and configured correctly.
✔ The Python 'six' package is found.
✔ Xcode version 12.5.1 satisfies minimum required version 10.
✖ WARNING: The Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.
```

Here are my environment variables, note these variables are identical in the user where tns doctor works fine.

```
$ANDROID_HOME = usr/local/share/android-sdk
$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = usr/local/share/android-sdk
$PATH=/Users/jenkins/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:
```

I have tried re-installing nativescript.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the path for android_home and android_sdk_root correct? Try using '/' before 'usr'.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Android SDK is installed and pointed at inside `$ANDROID_HOME`  and `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` according to the actual installation SDK folder (see below).

I found that the best way to check this is by installing Android Studio, and opening the SDK Manager:
[image]

Then double-check the Android-SDK location matches `$ANDROID_HOME`  and `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` above, and make sure that the selected packages are checked as in here:

[image]

(My installed Android SDK Build tools -orange dot- are version 30.0.2 and 26.0.3 and not the latest).

Also, make sure you've got the desired Android APIs installed on the following screen:

[image]

Make sure to reload environment variables by restarting terminal or by running `source ./bash_profile`.